# Python: Get the maximum of a certain index in a dictionary of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a dictionary set up like this:

`{attribute: [threshold, infogain]}`

where attribute is a string and infogain is a number. The list is always in the same format, so infogain's index is always 1.

and I would like to find the best attribute based on the value of infogain. I do need to keep threshold in there, or at least I need a way to store this so that all three values are associated and accessible.

My current attempt to get the max value of infogain is this:

`max(attribute.values()[1])`

Which causes an understandable error saying I'm trying to subscript `dict_values`.

and I was thinking about how to modify `max(attributes, key=attributes.get)` to somehow get me the dictionary key for the array with the max infogain, but no luck.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: What does best attribute mean? What type is info gain?

Comment: Will the incoming data structure always stay the same? Will the infogain always be at first index in the list?

Comment: Attribute is just a string, and infogain is a number. I just want to find the attribute which corresponds to the highest valued infogain

Comment: Try: `max(d.items(), key = lambda kv:kv[1][1])`, where d is the dictionary.  This provides the key, value pair.  To get the key: `max(d.items(), key = lambda kv:kv[1][1])[0]`

Comment: What is the variable name? What is attribute, a string? Does the dict has many items?

Comment: That worked DarrylG, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the max over the key/value pairs of the dictionary:

```
max_kv = max(d.items(), key = lambda kv:kv[1][1])
```

Max key is:

```
max_kv[0]  # since max_kv is a key/value pair
```

Example:

```
d = {
    "a1":[0.9, 1],
    "a2":[.25, 2],
    "a3":[.5, 5]
}
max_kv = ('a3', [0.5, 5])
```

So, max key is:

```
max_kv[0], which is a3
```